# Google type query using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have the following document:

```
{title:"Sennheiser HD 800"}
```

I want to all this queries return this document.

- senn
- heise
- sennheise
- sennheiser
- sennheiser 800
- sennheiser hd
- hd
- 800 hd
- hd ennheise

In short I want to find partial words either one or more.
In my map i am using this analyzer

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the map

```
{
  "title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "lower_case_sort": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the query is a simple string query

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "title.lower_case_sort"
      ],
      "query": "*800 hd*"
    }
  }
}
```

For example this query fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html).

Here is a blog post I wrote up about it for [Qbox](http://qbox.io):

https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

(Note that `"index_analyzer"` no longer works in ES 2.x; use `"analyzer"` instead; `"search_analyzer"` still works, though.)

Using this mapping (slightly modified from one in the blog post; I'll refer you there for an in-depth explanation):

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

index your document:

```
POST /test_index/doc/1
{
   "title": "Sennheiser HD 800"
}
```

and then any of your listed queries work, in the following form:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "title": {
            "query": "heise hd 800",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you only have a single term, then you don't need the `"operator"` part:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "title": "hd"
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to play around with it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a9accf67f1713ca99819f45ce0ac28adaea691a9